# How to automate AWS IOT console for testing?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I've been using python AWS IoT SDK for some time but it seems like it only allows interaction via things. Now I want to write automatic tests for my physical devices. But creating pseudo-thing like "tester" and giving it access to test devices topics seems wrong to me. I would like something similar to the AWS IoT console so that I could just subscribe and publish to topics without creating any extra things. Unfortunately, I can not find anything like that in docs.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do I understand correctly?:  You have been using AWS IoT "via things" for some time.  You want to know whether you can test the devices "without creating any __extra__ things" for testing, meaning do you need 2x thing per device?  If that is your question, then clearly no, max 1 thing per physical device is required.

Comment: By extra things, I meant any things that are not devices

Comment: OK, clear now.  `Things` has special meaning in AWS IoT.  You want Zero AWS `Things` in your architecture.  That does work.  See edited answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit:  "Can I use AWS IoT Core without the Things Registry?"

Yes, authenticated devices can communicate with the MQTT broker ("Device Gateway") without a corresponding `Thing` or `Device Shadow` for the physical devices.

> From the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/iot-core/faqs/?nc=sn&loc=5&dn=2):  **Q. Do I have to use the Registry and the Device Shadow?** You can have applications communicate directly to the connected devices using the Device Gateway and/or the Rules Engine in AWS IoT Core. However, we recommend using the Registry and the Device Shadow

Devices can `publish(topic, payload, qos, retain=False)` and `subscribe(topic, qos, callback=None)` using the MQTT client provided by the `mqtt.Connection` object provided by the [AWS IoT Device SDK for Python v2](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-crt-python/api/mqtt.html#awscrt.mqtt.Connection).

You can also bypass the message broker with [basic ingest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-basic-ingest.html) of messages to publish directly to an IoT Core rule (e.g. `$aws/rules/my-rule`).

---

It can be confusing because several IoT SDKs are involved:

(1) [Boto3 IoT Service](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iot.html):  manage AWS resources.  This is what you used to create your "things".  It is here you would call `create_topic_rule` to set up a [topic rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-repub-rule.html#iot-repub-rule-define) (e.g. `device/+/test`).

(2) [Boto3 IoTDataPlane Service](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iot-data.html):  "publish messages over HTTP (Publish) and retrieve, update, and delete shadows"

```py
response = client.publish(
    topic='string',
    qos=123,
    retain=True|False,
    payload=b'bytes'|file
)
```

(3) [AWS IoT Device SDK v2 for Python](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2): device-side "Python bindings for the AWS IoT Device API".  The repo Includes a pubsub [sample](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2/blob/main/samples/pubsub.py) to:

> send and receive messages through an MQTT connection. On startup, the device connects to the server, subscribes to a topic, and begins publishing messages to that topic. The device should receive those same messages back from the message broker, since it is subscribed to that same topic

Comment: The problem here is that IoTDataPlane allows message publishing only. 
IoT Device SDK works fine with full MQTT functionality but it forces me to create dummy things like "tester" which will do nothing but provide an entry point for my scripts. 
It looks suboptimal when each thing corresponds to a physical device and then we have this special, virtual thing only to allow mqtt access.